# "Array to string conversion" while writing MySQL output into a variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to write the output of a MySQL select into a variable. The problem is that i get the error "Array to String conversion".

```
    $user = mysql_query("select username from user");
echo "<table border='1'>";
if (isset($_POST['winneron'])) {
    echo "<tr>";
    while ($printuser = mysql_fetch_array($user)) {
        echo "<th align='center'>". $printuser['username'] . "</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    $user = mysql_query("select username from user");
    while ($printuser = mysql_fetch_array($user)) {
        $games = mysql_query("SELECT s.spielid, date, team1, team2, sieger, wettid, u.userid, w.spielid, team 
                              FROM user u, spiele s, wette w 
                              WHERE u.userid = w.userid 
                              AND u.username = '$printuser' 
                              AND w.spielid = s.spielid"); <-- Error line
        while ($printgames = mysql_fetch_array($games)) {
            if ( $printgames['sieger'] == $printgames['team1'] ) {
                echo "<tr><td align='center'><b>". strtoupper($printgames['sieger']) . "</b></td></tr>";    
            }
            else { 
                echo "<tr><td align='center'>". strtoupper($printgames['sieger']) . "</td></tr>"; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: on which line? note that if you try to fetch from the same $user twice, next time you might get an empty array

Comment: Edited the code so its easier to read.
Already thought that $user could be empty after the first fetch, so i added it again after the while loop.

Comment: You must understand that you're selecting multiple columns so you can't compare the username with an entire array of values. You must determine which index of the array, i.e. the username index, you wish to compare in your search query. Use prepared statements and bind values into variables, otherwise the code gets messy and will not work, but it's easy to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND u.username = '$printuser'` replace it with `AND u.username = '".$printuser['username']."'`

Answer (score 2):

`$printuser` is a array and you are using it like a string